# App crashes and failed to bind $PORT 60 seconds

Tags: php, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I have the problem of my app in Heroku, my set up is Nginx, Docker and Php, and a simple Php script. after issuing release command in Heroku CLI and open the app, my app launches in browser but it crashes.

here is the log.

```
2020-05-30T15:46:38.733789+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-30T15:46:51.620126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `nginx -g daemon\ off\;`
2020-05-30T15:47:52.178537+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-05-30T15:47:52.210903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-05-30T15:47:52.317640+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-05-30T15:47:52.373907+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM  ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl zip unzip  \
            php7.4 php7.4-fpm \
            nginx


COPY ./webapp /var/www/myapp

WORKDIR /var/www/myapp

# ADD default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY default.conf.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# for ubuntu
RUN useradd -m myuser
USER myuser


CMD /bin/bash -c "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

**UPDATE**

After adding port as what suggested in the comment, now new error occurs

> /bin/bash: envsubst: command not found

Comment: You have to pass a value for $PORT variable. The app is trying to bind to $PORT. `Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your Dockerfile for `CMD`, you are `$PORT` and you have to pass that environment variable in your Dockerfile or while running the container.

```
CMD /bin/bash -c "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

If you want to supply in Dockerfile,

```
FROM  ubuntu:latest
ENV PORT=80 # Add this line
...
...
CMD /bin/bash -c "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

or If you want to override at runtime, pass it with `docker run` command

```
docker run -e PORT=8008 imageName
```